# Format and video Resolution like WMP with MediaElement WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml, video, resolution, mediaelement

Hey I would like to know if its possible to do something like that with the MediaElement in WPF:
http://img11.hostingpics.net/pics/374632Captur2e.png

And Like that:
http://img11.hostingpics.net/pics/403059Capture.png

So I When I resize my window the Default resolution stay the same.

Thanks

Comment: I guess you mean keeping the aspect ratio of the content. Yes, MediaElement does that by default. To change that behaviour, set the Stretch property.

Comment: But how can I put the MediaElement FullScreen like that (http://img11.hostingpics.net/pics/567587cap.png) without stretching the whole aspect

Comment: Did you try anything, i mean put in in a Grid for example and see how it looks?

Comment: But with a mediaElement in a grid how can I keep the original aspect ratio?

Comment: MediaElement does that for you. Go ahead and give it a try.

Comment: I try it with a grid but it still Stretch the entire image of the video

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just have a look at the code below. It is a MediaElement in a Border in a Grid. The Border is only there to show that the Grid is filled completely. Running this code and resizing the containing window shows that MediaElement well preserves the aspect ratio of its content (a behaviour that may be altered by setting the Stretch property).

```
<Grid>
    <Border BorderThickness="5" BorderBrush="White" Background="Black">
        <MediaElement Source="C:\Users\Public\Videos\Sample Videos\Wildlife.wmv"/>
    </Border>
</Grid>
```